# ORA-04092: cannot ROLLBACK in a trigger

Tags: oracle, rollback

I created a trigger to raise an error when there is an update that causes the total balance to go below -100. I also need the trigger to stop the update from happening. I am getting the error report but I cannot rollback the update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOLUTION2

AFTER UPDATE OF balance ON ACCOUNT
DECLARE 
    balance_sum NUMBER(9,2);

BEGIN
    balance_sum := 0;

    SELECT SUM(balance)
      INTO balance_sum 
      FROM ACCOUNT 
     WHERE balance < 0 
     GROUP BY bank_name
    HAVING SUM(balance) < -100;

    IF (balance_sum != 0) THEN 
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'The total value of balance on all bank accounts located in a bank and such that the balance of the accounts is negative, cannot be less than -100'); 
    END IF;

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Balance is updated!');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);

END;
/
```

Comment: Have you tried placing a `ROLLBACK;` command in the WHEN OTHERS exception?

Comment: Remove `WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);` you’re telling it to pretend the trigger was successful if it errored. If you allow the default behaviour to happen (ie the error gets raised) then you would get the normal statement level rollback automatically.